# tensor flow copy an entire graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a fairly generic genetic algorithm implementation I'm TensorFlow. I have an implementation that is slow and am trying to increase its speed. I will provide a really simple example of where the program is getting slow and would welcome recommendations of improving the speed of the current implementation.

Let us say that we create the following:

```
W  = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(Warr, dtype=tf.float32))
X  = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(3, None))
y  = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None) )
```

And we want to find `W` for the condition:

```
Warr = np.array([[0.1, 0, 0]])
Xarr = np.random.random((3, 100))
yarr = np.dot(Warr, Xarr)
```

A naive implementation (like the one I have created) goes thus:

1 a cost function is created for this implementation:

```
yHat  = tf.matmul(W, X)
costFunction = tf.reduce_mean( tf.sqrt((y - yHat)*(y - yHat)) )
```

Note that the cost function can be arbitrarily complex and is not known *apriori*. Hence, it is something that will be passed into a class. Note that the rest of the code are excerpts within a class, but the main idea is easy to follow:

2 A population is generated (within a class).

```
self.population   = []
for i in tqdm(range(self.GAconfig['numChildren'])):
    temp = []
    for j, v in enumerate(locVars):
        v = (v + (np.random.random( v.shape ) - 0.5) * 2)
        v = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(v, dtype=tf.float32))
        temp.append(v)
    self.population.append( temp )
```

Finding the cost function for this population is a rather arduous task. First copy the weights in the population into the original weight tensor and then calculate the original cost function:

```
for ps in self.population:
    for i, v in enumerate(self.variables): 
        sess.run(tf.assign( self.variables[i], ps[i] ))

    result = sess.run(self.costFunction, feed_dict={
                            self.X : X, self.y : y
                            })
```

This implementation is obviously slow. One possible way would be to to generate a set of cost function tensors rather than weight variables, which can all be updated at once.

However, this is the point at which I am not sure what a "good implementation" would be that can improve the speed of the current implementation. Ant help will be greatly appreciated ...

**Note**: The full implementation is available here:

https://github.com/sankhaMukherjee/tfNNGA

- It is at its very early stages, so the code at the moment is very bad.
- The implementation of the GA function can be found in the file `src/lib/GA/GA.py`
- Crossover is found within the `GA` class
- This is called from within the file `src/moduleGA/moduleGA.py`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried next functions?

```
copy_variable_to_graph
copy_op_to_graph
get_copied_op
```

[source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py)